# running Unity 2d in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, unity-2d

I'm trying to run Unity 2d in xubuntu, I installed the packages but when I try to run it I get

> [FATAL] Settings schema 'com.canonical.Unity' is not installed

How can I get it to run? I'd like to install as little stuff as possible.

Comment: What packages have you installed and how? If you've used coomand line, can you provide the commands.

Comment: I used synaptic, I searched for unity-2d and installed the main package. Since it did not work, I tried to install all the other packages found with this name but to no avail.

Comment: @AntoineRodriguez - I am running 12.04 and it will be supported for years to come. And it's faster than Unity, computer I'm using runs very fast with XFCE and very slow with Unity, I wanted to test it with Unity 2d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think unfortunately you will have to install more dependencies, and the one you are missing is `gnome-session`, without which `unity 2d` can't run, and you get the error message you received. This is actually detailed at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/986575); installing `unity 2d` manually from Synaptic does not automatically pull in the correct dependencies.

Running an `apt-cache rdepends unity-2d` proves this:

```
unity-2d
Reverse Depends:
  unity-2d-dbg
  unity-2d-common
  libunity9
  unity-2d-dbg
  unity-2d-common
  ubuntu-desktop
  libunity9
  gnome-session
 |gnome-session
```

If you don't want absolutely everything that `gnome-session` includes, you could try installing it with the `--no-install-recommends` flag and this will install just the essential elements needed for `unity-2d`.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session --no-install-recommends
```

It should **not** be necessary to install the `ubuntu-desktop` package as well, but keep that in mind if all else fails.

Using `unity-2d` should now be possible and it should be a login option at the Xubuntu screen and if you have any visual defects in it is also worth installing the following, according to this [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/948762) report.

```
sudo apt-get install light-themes ubuntu-mono ubuntu-wallpapers-precise gnome-themes-standard
```

As the two bug reports at Launchpad have proven, you do need to install a fair amount of things to run `unity-2d` on Xubuntu.

Comment: "then run it again without the --no-install-recommends", I think it cannot be done in that way after installation is done. Because you will be given a message like "gnome-session is already in the newest version"

Comment: @Anwar Yes you are correct- I was thinking of something else at the time-will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your dependencies, when I saw this in the past I used dpkg to list them and it turns out some of the dependencies were wrong and somehow unity-2d-places and unity-2d-spread were not installed.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer a bit? I think, it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install `ubuntu-desktop` package if you want to be sure to have all packages for unity:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```